# Cross origin request -401 with POSTMAN

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, postman

Currently am working on Spring boot back end **API** services.This *API* expecting two values one for path variables and others for request body.Using **POSTMAN** application for making request.

[image]

When i click into the send button it will show like this

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-07-31T05:57:15.178+0000",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/Service/api/ea/saveConfig/$%7Bhost%7D"
}
```

**Controller class**

I have added cross origin annotation like blow

**Edit1**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8000")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/ea")
public class ServiceConfigController
{
    @PostMapping(value = "/saveConfig/{host}", produces = "application/json")
        public ResponseEntity<JsonNode> saveConfig(@PathVariable String host,
                @RequestBody JsonNode data) throws JsonProcessingException
        {
            try
            {
                ResponseEntity<JsonNode> result = configService.saveConfiguration(host, data);

                return result;
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {           
                return new ResponseEntity<>(data, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
    }
}
```

If we are making request from **POSTMAN** what will be the cross origin.I tried few things but not helpful.

Please suggest a valid solution.

Comment: Please add more information, e.g. your controller method. 401 indicates a problem with missing authentication.

Comment: Also, probably not related to the 401, your request url shows `${host}` and you want `{{host}}` if you're trying to use a postman environment variable

Comment: @tpschmidt updated the code

Answer (score 0):

The POSTMAN path variable should be {{host}} instead of ${host}. Please share your pom xml. Best guess is that you may use spring security to secure you API.
Please remove the dependency from your pom and retry again.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

If spring security is a must, you may try to add Auth to your POSTMAN and retry. Username is user and password is generated and printed in your console.
For example,

```
2020-07-31 15:19:01.727  INFO 3296 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 
Using generated security password: ae4b7465-ab44-416d-96e3-8d122f755e04
2020-07-31 15:19:01.811  INFO 3296 --- [           main]
```

[image: postman-auth-screen]